# logfile deleted on Oracle database how to re-create it?

Tags: oracle, log-files, corruption

For my database assignment we were looking into 'database corruption' and I was asked to delete the second redo log file which I have done with the command: `rm log02a.rdo` this was in the $HOME/ORADATA/u03 directory.

Now I started up my database using `startup pfile=$PFILE nomount` then I mounted it using the command `alter database mount;` now when I try to open it `alter database open;` it gives me this error:

```
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel 
Process ID: 22125 
Session ID: 25 Serial number: 1
```

I am assuming this is because the second redo log file is missing. There is still log01a.rdo, but not the one I have deleted. How can I go about recovering this now so that I can open my database again?

I have looked into the database create scripts, and it specified the log02a.rdo file to be size 10M and part of group 2.

If I do `select group#, member from v$logfile;` I get:

```
  1
/oradata/student_db/user06/ORADATA/u03/log01a.rdo

  2
/oradata/student_db/user06/ORADATA/u03/log02a.rdo

  3
/oradata/student_db/user06/ORADATA/u03/log03a.rdo

  4
/oradata/student_db/user06/ORADATA/u03/log04a.rdo
```

So it is part of group 2. If I try to add the log02a.rdo file again "already part of the database". If I drop group 2 and then add it again with these commands:

```
ALTER DATABASE 
  ADD LOGFILE GROUP 2 ('$HOME/ORADATA/u03/log02a.rdo')
      SIZE 10M;
```

Nothing. Supposedly alters the database, but it still won't start up. Any ideas what I can do to re-create this and be able to open my database again?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to recreate it including the data that was in it, unless you happen to have a backup ofc.
You can start the database reset the logs and recreate an empty file

try:

```
 startup nomount;
 alter database mount; 
 alter database open resetlogs;
```

more info http://web.njit.edu/info/limpid/DOC/backup.102/b14191/osrecov009.htm